# getting texture picture for opengl through resource file(c++/visual studio 2008)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opengl, resource-files

when you create a new opengl project in visual studio 2008, you get three folders: one for header files, one for source files and one for resource files.

Is it feasible to put a jpg picture in resource files and then link to it to load it as a texture?
i want to load jpg pictures as textures, but i want to do that through resource files so that the debug exe contains those files.

how can i link to the pictures that i put in resource files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe If you link the texture as a resource, it will be stored **inside your `.exe` file**. That's not a commonly used solution - usually you'd want to store resources in a separate folder (or an archive/VFS file) next to your `.exe` - then the texture will be loaded from this file after you run your program. This also means that you won't have to recompile the big .exe file whenever you replace or modify a texture. So my answer to your first question is - no, it's not really feasible, unless you *need* to have the whole application with resources in a single `.exe`.

If you like the latter option with files (which I recommend), then the easiest way to use the texture from file is to use a loader library like [SOIL](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html) which simplifies OpenGL texture loading from any format to a single line of code.

Answer (score 1):

In the project's `resource view`, right click `yourproject.rc`. Click the `Import...` button. Select the JPEG file(s) you want to insert. When it asks you to name the type, name it something like "JPEG". From there, the JPEG will be compiled into your executable.

To load it, you use [`FindResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648042%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get a handle to the resource, then [`LoadResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648046%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to load it into memory, then [`LockResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648047%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get its address. From there you can use a normal JPEG decoder to get it into a form that you can use as a texture. Alternatively, you could download [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/) to handle almost all of that for you.